# how to use mediaSession for android api >=19

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat, mediasession

I'm trying to incorporate `MediaSession` into my `Service`, but, using the `android.media.MediaSession` doesn't work because calling `mediaSession.release()` gives me an error saying call is available only in `api level 21` while I'm targeting api level 19.

I had searched, and it seems it's not available in [androidx.media](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/media) as well. Where is the `MediaSession` or `MediaSessionCompat` located for androidx users?

Comment: try this - https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-mediasession-part-1-3-e4d2725f18e4

Comment: @Sachin , it mentions nothing of androidx or import MediaSession

Comment: check media 2 api , https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media2/session/MediaSession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Using a media session guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/working-with-a-media-session), the correct class is still [`android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat) (you'll note that the class still remains under the 'AndroidX' set of documentation and is still part of the `androidx.media` artifact).

The class remains in the old package simply because the nested class, [`MediaSessionCompat.Token`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.Token) is `Parcelable` and is part of the public API and therefore cannot have its package named while remaining compatible with apps still built against the old Support Library classes.

Comment: you mean `android.support.v4/v7...` and `androidx....` are not libraries to be used mutually exclusively?

Comment: This link that you've provided: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat  doesn't seem to remain in the `androidx` section as you've mentioned

Comment: and the media support library says that media-compat is deprecated; https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#media-playback and recommends using androidx ,and says a new version is available for androidx but doesn't say where

Comment: there's even a `androidx.media.MediaSessionManager` I wonder if these would cause trouble with the `v4`libs.

Comment: It is very clearly in the 'AndroidX' section in the left navigation of the page. Like I said, this class **purposefully did not move to the androidx package because that would break compatibility**. It absolutely, 100% is part of the `androidx.media` library.

Comment: but it is true in most cases that `v4` and `androidx` are mutually exclusively usable?

Comment: `androidx.media` is the only AndroidX library group that still contains classes in the `android.support.v4` packages (as it was the only library that had public `Parcelable` implementations meant to be sent to and from other apps).

Comment: BTW do you know if notificaiton.Builder.setsTyle(...) is the only place where we could set a mediaSession? It seems pretty weird it's set in a style attribute

Comment: `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` is the correct style to use for media apps and that's where you call `setMediaSession()`.